# Ipywidgets HTML conversion of output doesn't visualize plotly graphs

Tags: javascript, python, html, plotly, ipywidgets

for my bachelors thesis a few years ago I teached myself Python to do some data science and host a interactive "webversion" of my thesis.
In essence, I created my webversion by nesting ipywidgets within each other and then converting the output of these nested nests into HTML code. Then, I simply uploaded this HTML code on nelify as a static single page website.

Unfortunatly, there seems to be a problem with the dependencies of the nested plotly graphs as I understand by this error code:

```
Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Model class 'FigureModel' from module 'plotlywidget' is loaded but can not be instantiated
TypeError: i._deserialize_state is not a function
    at $n._make_model (https://unpkg.com/@jupyter-widgets/html-manager@*/dist/embed-amd.js:16:1002557)
```

I tried to play around in the dpendencies within the HTML file, but to no avail.

You can find the website (and therfore full code) under

https://covidmaxdrawdown.netlify.app/

I hope you understand the intanglements of dpendencies better than I did.

Kind regards and thank you